# Reset field value from another field Primefaces

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

View:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="examId" value="#{examrequisitionsController.selected.examId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateExamrequisitionsRequiredMessage_examId}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{examsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" var="examIdItem" itemValue="#{examIdItem}"/>
     <p:ajax listener="#{examrequisitionsController.getExamPrice()}" update="price" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="price" widgetVar="widgetPrice" value="#{examrequisitionsController.selected.price}" title="#{bundle.CreateExamrequisitionsTitle_price}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateExamrequisitionsRequiredMessage_price}" readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}" maxlength="7">
     <f:validator validatorId="decimalValidator" />
</p:inputText>
```

Controller:

```
public void getExamPrice() {
      EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SystemCardiologyReportsPU").createEntityManager();
      Exams exam = (Exams) em.createNamedQuery("Exams.findById").setParameter("id", this.selected.getExamId().getId()).getSingleResult();
      this.selected.setPrice(exam == null ? null : exam.getPrice());        
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('change', '#ExamrequisitionsCreateForm\\:examId_input', function () {   
    if (this.value === '')
        jQuery('#ExamrequisitionsCreateForm\\:price').val('');    
});
```

I want to make something to reset the value of the input "price" if "Select One" option is selected in examId field.

That JS function works, but after the function JS reset the value of field, the tag ajax automatically auto update to the last valid value.

Would be easier to make it in Controller, but the ajax is not going to controller, when I select the first option, that's why I'm trying with JS.

Or any function that disables "Select One" after the user select any other option using JS.

I tried something like:

`$('select [value=""]').attr('style', 'display:none');`

Comment: If the solution worked, accepting the answer and/or up-voting would help

Answer (score 0):

I assume examId is an int. So can you  please remove

```
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

And add

```
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="0" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

I think the null converter is not working as your selectOneMenu value is an int and cannot understand the null. You can remove the js script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. No, examId isn't an int, is an object of Exam (this nomenclature is because of Database). Anyway, I solved the problem using  `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemDisabled="true" />`, so there's no way to select that option again.

Comment: Great. Next time you can explore  a jsf converter for exam.